# EF Core добавить существующую таблицу в контекст

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Есть база данных созданная как code-first, с помощью миграции. В эту базу данных экпортируется таблица. Возможно ли работать с этой таблицей через EF? Те каким то образом добавить ее в context ?

Comment: Руками, например.

Comment: Все изменения в БД при подходе code-first должны происходить через миграции, иначе вы потом сами концы потеряете, как поднять production-like базу данных. Ну и как бы контекст БД - это просто класс, сущности - тоже классы, то есть вы можете добавить ещё сущность в контекст, но имейте ввиду, что после этого снепшот схемы в БД и в коде будет различаться и вы не сможете больше полагаться на миграци, если вы добавляете таблицы в БД вручную

Comment: @tym32167 я уже понял что различаются, он ругается при попытке создать уже существующую таблицу в базе. Возможен какой то выход или это тупиковая ветвь?

Comment: Лазать руками в БД, которая создается миграциями - имхо, это последнее, что бы я мог себе позволить, когда уже совсем выхода нет. Что вам вместо этого мешает добавить такую сущность в контекст, чтобы по ней сгенерировать именно такую таблицу, какую вам надо?

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю у вас есть база данных часть которая из code first и туда добавили через саму базу еще таблицы. То в этом случае создайте новый класс с тем же названием (или через аннотации) и свойствами и добавьте его в контекст.

Если таблиц много можно создать консольное приложения через code second к вашей базе он создать классы с свойствами как и в таблице

Comment: не code second, а database first :)

Comment: так же говорят code second